# Why is Thunderbird trying to access the domain associated with an email address?

Tags: firewall, thunderbird

When I'm composing a new message in Thunderbird, I enter an email address - let's say `mail@example.com` - I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to jump to the subject field and now my application firewall (LittleSnitch on a Mac) tells me that Thunderbird is trying to connect to `example.com`. Why? The same thing is happening on Windows machines.

How can I stop Thunderbird from "ruining my privacy"?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What exactly is LittleSnitch telling you? Which port is Thunderbird trying to connect on?

Comment: @bertieb Thank you! Port 443. I think it has something to do with autoconfig, as the Thunderbird Developer Tools tell me the requested URL is `https://example.com/.well-known/openpgpkey/hu/someweirdstring`. Okay, next suspect: Enigmail?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I get the privacy side of this. I mean, it's the _same domain_ in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is a feature of *Key Discovery*

Thunderbird is trying to access a URL along the lines of:

> `https://example.com/.well-known/openpgpkey/hu/someweirdstring`

This is to look up an OpenPGP key associated with the address(es) you've typed in the `To:` field:

> *(preamble)*

> This memo describes a method to associate OpenPGP keys with a mail
> address and how to look them up using a web service with a well-known
> URI.

> (...intervening sections snipped...)

> To form the URI, the following parts are
> concatenated:

> o  The scheme `"https://"`,

> o  the domain-part,

> o  the string `"/.well-known/openpgpkey/hu/"`,

> o  and the above constructed 32 octet string.

> For example the URI to lookup the key for `Joe.Doe@Example.ORG` is:

> ```
> https://example.org/.well-known/openpgpkey/hu/iy9q119eutrkn8s1mk4r39qejnbu3n5q
> ```

From [**OpenPGP Web Key Service**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-koch-openpgp-webkey-service-05#section-3.1), '3.1 Key Discovery'.

## What is the culprit?

You say you have the Engimail add-on installed:

> Enigmail is an add-on to the mail client of Mozilla Thunderbird and SeaMonkey allowing users to access the authentication and encryption features provided by GnuPG. Thus Enigmail enables Mozilla Thunderbird and SeaMonkey to send and receive digitally signed and/or encrypted messages using the OpenPGP standard.

Enigmail supports (among other things), *"OpenPGP key management interface"*

from [**What is Enigmail**](https://www.enigmail.net/index.php/en/documentation).

I couldn't find support for key lookup specifically after a cursory search, but it is likely Enigmail supports this.

## How can I protect my privacy?

You have a number of options:

- let your application firewall block the requests
- disable Enigmail

or,

- let the lookups continue, on the basis you are emailing someone at that domain anyway

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! It seems as if disabling "Autocrypt" and disabling "automatically send encrypted" (in the non-junior-expert-settings of Enigmail) stops automatic key discovery.

Comment: My pleasure, it was an interesting question :) If you're happy for me to, I will edit those settings into the answer (or you can add you own answer) for future reference- comments are notionally temporary!

Comment: After a few more days with Enigmail, I noticed that disabling Autocrypt and "automatically send encrypted" doesn't resolve this issue. I'll investigate a little.